# "Area code not set" error. Still getting this error after a lot of search?

Tags: magento2, error, command-line

First of all, I have to tell you that I have spent a lot of time researching and I have done all the solutions I have came across but I'm still getting this error when I run `setup:di:compile`

The full error is as follows:

```
Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 3 mins 384.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.


  [Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException]                       
  Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.  

  [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]  
  Area code is not set
```

I'm trying to test some functionality and made a quick command line to test it. My entire class is as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Falak\MyCommands\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class CustomerCredit extends Command
{

    protected $transaction;
    protected $appState;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magestore\Customercredit\Model\Transaction $transaction,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->appState = $appState;
        $this->transaction = $transaction;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('falak:credit')
            ->setDescription('Test Customer Credit');

        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $originalArea = $this->appState->getAreaCode();
        $this->appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
        $output->writeln("Hello World!");
        $this->appState->setAreaCode($originalArea);
    }


}
```

**Notes:**

1. I have tried setting the area code in the constructor directly
2. I have tried setting it in the configure
3. I have tried to set it every where at the same time
4. When I remove all reference to `\Magestore\Customercredit\Model\Transaction` it compiles without any problems. But I need this reference as I'm trying to call some of the functions in this class

**UPDATE:** Here is my `di.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="commandTest" xsi:type="object">Falak\MyCommands\Console\CommandTest</item>
                <item name="testCustomerCredit" xsi:type="object">Falak\MyCommands\Console\CustomerCredit</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Did you define di.xml file in etc folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please define di.xml file in Module Falak\MyCommands\etc folder and put below code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="falak:credit" xsi:type="object">Falak\MyCommands\Console\CustomerCredit</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
</type>
```

Now clean all cache and run setup:di:compile and let me know if you still have issue.

You are also missing code to get area code in protected function execute():

```
try {
        $areaCode = $this->appState->getAreaCode();
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        // if area code is not set then magento generate exception "LocalizedException"
        $this->appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the di.xml file I'm already using. I have also tried moving it completely and using your di.xml with the same result (without the last </type> as I think it's a typo)

Comment: Now check my updated answer and let me know.If you are still facing issue just move di.xml file in etc/frontend folder and run command again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried with the same result. Which puzzles me as I expect this to work since now I'm catching the LocalizedException. But it's still being thrown when I compile.

Comment: Ok,I think it seems another issue.Please follow this extension as this have same functinality  https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

Comment: Hello @HassanAl-Jeshi ,is your issue resolved?

Comment: Thank you @akgola for asking. I have resolved it by not using direct injection and use ObjectManager::getInstance() instead. Since this command is only for testing purposes, I think I will be fine.